# Some stupid problems with wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

i habe updated today my wordpress installation.

And everything works fine, but only the catecory pages.

Get errot tha in the index.php of my theme file, invalid argument foreach.

```
$jsFiles = glob('*.js');

foreach($jsFiles as $jsFile)....
```

so he cant find the js files... or what? All other pages works fine - tags, pages, posts... i cant explain it :(

Answer (score 0):

It means that what you supplied to the foreach construct is not an array. You can do something like this to see if the value is an array before you try to foreach over it:

```
if (is_array($jsFiles)) {
    foreach($jsFiles as $jsFiles) // ....
} else {
    // $jsFiles is not an array
}
```

Comment: i have add is_array to my code... now i get no errors, but theme doenst work... for categorys

Answer (score 0):

Yup looks likes it can't find the files. Maybe changing to the directory where the files are located might help

Comment: hmmm maybe the rewrite is messing things up? the .htacess that you're surely running with WP